# How do I access the "newPageLoaded" flag in Selenium using the Ruby client?

Tags: ruby, selenium

From reading the Selenium documentation, I can see that there is a "newPageLoaded" flag that gets set when you perform a page-loading action. I'm trying to find out if there's a way to get at the value of that flag as the page is loading.

How to do this using the Ruby client would be great. : )

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this?

```
selenium.getEval("selenium.browserbot.isNewPageLoaded()");
```

Comment: I tried that, but it returns false regardless of whether or not the page has finished loading. My JavaScript-fu is not that strong, so I'm trying to figure out how to inspect the browserbot object to see if I can find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Note that if you're using selenium.getEval() it *should always return false, because every apparently every command that gets executed sets it to false. Trying to figure out if there is a way to see it now...